# python what is this line doing?

Tags: python, struct

I cannot find out what this line is doing:
`p = struct.pack(">b", x)+p[1:]`

can you help me on this? I think it is placing sth at the end of the struct. Is is also possible to place sth in the middle of that struct? Things like: `p = struct.pack(">b", x)+p[2:]` don't seem to help. Any ideas on this?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It replaces the first byte of `p` with a byte representing the value of `x`. You may or may not have already read this, but [here is the documentation for the `struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).

**Edit:** To replace the second byte, try this:

```
p = p[:1] + struct.pack(">b", x) + p[2:]
```

Comment: thx for your help. of course I read it, but I don't understand why I cannot replace the 2nd byte of p :-S Actually I need to do exactely that. So if you have any hint on that I would be very happy :)

Comment: awesome! thx a lot, you saved my day :) I'm sure I tried this... thx man

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to all that string slicing, which is quite inefficient, consider using a bytearray

```
>>> import struct
>>> p=bytearray('foobar')
>>> p
bytearray(b'foobar')
>>> p[4]=struct.pack(">b", 64)
>>> p
bytearray(b'foob@r')
```

bytearray has lots of string methods available

```
>>> dir(p)
['__add__', '__alloc__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__',
'__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__',
'__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__',
'__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
'__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
'__subclasshook__', 'append', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode',
'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'extend', 'find', 'fromhex', 'index', 'insert',
'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper',
'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'pop', 'remove', 'replace',
'reverse', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip',
'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title',
'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

and is easy to convert back to string when you are done mutating it

```
>>> str(p)
'foob@r'
```